# Why do we requires a jssecerts file when tomcat is provided with a keystore

Tags: java, security, tomcat, ssl, certificate

I generated a keypair via keytool into a new keystore called keystore. In tomcat, in the connecter for the secure port, i pointed the keystore to the said keystore.
Now when i access tomcat via chrome i get a warning about the certificate. I clicked on the lock icon and saved the certificate and imported it into chrome. Now when i access my service, i do get the green icon BUT i get a exception - PKIX path building failed:  unable to find valid certification path to requested target. 
This was fixed using the InstallCert script that i got off the web, which created the jssecerts file which i moved into the jre directory.
All is working as expected, but I dont understand why we need to create the jssecerts file.

If i understand the flow correctly, when the browser goes to the secure port, the server picks up the certificate from the keystore and sends it to the browser . However since its a self signed certificate, the browser complains and then i either say, i understand the risk and proceed or i import that certificate into chrome (which makes the certificate trusted).
If the above understanding is correct then i wont need the jssecerts file. Obviously there is some thing wrong as the above wont work till i run the InstallCert and move the jssecerts to security folder in the jre. (instead of jssecerts i could have probably added it to cacerts but the point is the same - why?)

I tried configuring tomcat with a truststore and pointed to the keystore but ...

Would appreciate the security gurus out there could throw some light on this.

thanks
-anish

Answer (score 0):

Java can't see Chrome's trusted certificate repository. It uses its own.

Comment: Thanks EJP for your reply.

Comment: Thanks EJP for your reply. Unfortunately my ignorance prevents me from appreciating the answer. In the above scenario only the server has a certificate. When the SSL handshake starts the server sends the certificate from the keystore to the client - the client, chrome, validates the certificate against its trusted certificate repository. Since  the certificate was imported  into chrome earlier, this is validated. Its the return leg between chrome and the server which is confusing. What does chrome send back for the server to check in Java's trusted certificate repository?